# How do I perform a remote build for iOS using PhoneGap on Windows?

Tags: ios, windows, cordova

This is my first hybrid App. I'm getting about a dozen of these error message

```
C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\TypeFunctions>phonegap remote build ios
[phonegap] compressing the app...
rm: could not remove file (code EBUSY): C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\TypeFunctions\build\www/lib/images/icons-svg/mail-black.svg
```

There is only 1 [search result](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=phonegap+remote+build+ios+%5Bphonegap%5D+compressing+the+app...+rm%3A+could+not+remove+file+%28code+%2BEBUSY%29) on the entire web.

My target platform is Windows 8.1. I am using PhoneGap 5.4.0.

---

Strange, I tried it again, but now I got a different error. No mention of what the error was though. Terrible software.

```
C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\TypeFunctions>phonegap remote build ios
[phonegap] compressing the app...
skipping existing file: mail-black.svg
skipping existing file: tag-white.svg
skipping existing file: user-black.svg
skipping existing file: user-white.svg
[phonegap] uploading the app...
[phonegap] building the app...
   [error] error occured while building the ios app
```

---

I managed to get a stack trace.

```
Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 'C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\TypeFunctions\build' 
at rethrow (fs.js:48:21) 
at maybeCallback (fs.js:66:42) 
at Object.fs.rmdir (fs.js:797:14) 
at Object.module.exports.cleanup (C:\Users\Chloe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\phonegap-build\lib\phonegap-build\create\zip.js:119:16) 
at Object.callback (C:\Users\Chloe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\phonegap-build\lib\phonegap-build\build\remote.js:71:21) 
at Request._callback (C:\Users\Chloe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\phonegap-build-api\lib\api.js:229:26) 
at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\Chloe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\phonegap-build-api\node_modules\request\main.js:122:22) 
at emitTwo (events.js:87:13) 
at Request.emit (events.js:172:7) 
at Request. (C:\Users\Chloe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\phonegap-build-api\node_modules\request\main.js:655:16)
```

---

#### Additional Information

The EBUSY and ENOTEMPTY errors were caused by [`guard`](http://guardgem.org/) running. It might be possible to have it run with [-w option](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Command-line-options-for-Guard#-w--watchdir-option).

I'm still getting the `[error] error occured while building the ios app` without reason. I'm using PhoneGap CLI and PhoneGap Build. I thought that part was obvious with the actual command line provided. The target platform was iOS. I thought that was given away by the command line too. The (default) `platform` tags in `config.xml` are

```
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
<engine name="ios" spec="~3.9.2" />
```

The app was created with the [jQuery template](http://docs.phonegap.com/references/phonegap-cli/templates/) and command `phonegap create myApp --template jquery-mobile-starter` and then modified.

Comment: Is this your first App? What is your target platform and their target versions? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001)? Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 Yes it is my first PhoneGap app. Updated. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Okay. You have a slight problem following directions - as well. As such, you need to read the remainder of this FAQ, [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md). In addition, you are NOT using *Phonegap Build*, as that is a cloud-based service - which you are not using. FWIW, you cannot perform a remote build - unless you start using the *Phonegap Build API* - which you have no indications of doing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I am using PhoneGap Build, because I signed up at https://build.phonegap.com/ and I logged in and followed the documentation here http://docs.phonegap.com/references/phonegap-cli/remote-usage/

Comment: Yes. This is all part of your misunderstanding. Please read the FAQ. FWIW: you are using the wrong documents. If you are using *Phonegap Build*, this is your documentation: https://build.phonegap.com/docs ALSO, notice in the middle of your URL it says *phonegap-cli* **remote-usage** is not what you are thinking.

Comment: Have you gotten a certificate yet? It's a unique requirement for developing iOS apps. If you can build an Android app without any errors, while iOS emits errors... this is a probably reason. Read: http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/support_failed-builds.md.html#no_cert